# Probability Distribution of Picking letters from the word "PROBABILITY"

Tags: probability-theory

Pick letters with replacement from "PROBABILITY" until you get the letter ‘B’.

Let N = # of letters drawn and X = # of times the letter ‘P’ is drawn.

Find the probability P(X = x). Do you recognize this distribution?

This is one of my practice problem from probability theory. My professor explains that this question is the same as two players playing a game. P1 wins if the pick is P. P2 wins if the pick is B. And thus the distribution should be a geometric distribution.

I am not fully understanding this argument. Can someone please explain more concretely how to translate this problem into a geometric distribution? And what would the final expression for P(X = x) be?

Comment: The idea here is that the draws other than $P,B$ are irrelevant.  You might as well assume that you only have $P,B,B$ from which you are drawing with replacement.  Then you are counting the number of fails ($P$ draws) before a success (a $B$ draw) and that is a geometric process.  For instance, $P(X=0)=\frac 23$, clearly, since the first meaningful draw is $B$ with probability $\frac 23$.

Comment: @lulu Ok I see. Then P(X = x) = (1/3)^x*2/3 correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  $\,$

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your professor's analogy. Geometric distribution is a series of probabilities until the first success. For coin tossing to get a head, it's $\frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 18$ etc. So, what is the probability of getting a B in the first selection, followed by the probability of getting a B in the second selection etc etc.

Comment: He is saying P(X=x) is the probability P1 wins x times before the first time P2 wins.

Comment: That makes sense. Note the replacement so that the next probability of a success in the series is subject to a common ratio.